# How to make google sheet script Ignore fields with formulas

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have built a script which works perfectly fine, however for usability I want to populate the fields queried to build the payload, via formulas.

Issue: if I have fields without values but formulas, the script sends empty values to the api resulting in an error stopping follow up functions.

If I manually set the array of fields including formulas it works.

Solution I am looking for: a code line for my script, to break upon meeting a field with a formula instead of a value.

I hope this question/issue is clear.

I tried this code but it did not work:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < data_statistics.length; i++) {
    if (data_statistics[i] === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    else if (data_statistics[i][0].includes("=")) {
      break;
    }
```

This is the working function:

```js
function Mean(){
  
  var sheet_statistics = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mean") 
  var data_statistics = sheet_statistics.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var token = _requestToken();
  
  var col_start = 2
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data_statistics.length; i++) {
    if (data_statistics[i] === undefined) {
         break;
    }
   
    
    // Build payloads and apply small sanity checks payload specific
    
    // Payload same typo
    var payload = Object();
    for (var j = col_start; j < data_statistics[0].length; j++) {
      _buildPayload(payload, data_statistics[0][j].split('.'), data_statistics[i][j]);
    }
    payload.filters.divisionLevel100 = String(payload.filters.divisionLevel100);
    
    // Get statistics
    var statistics = _getOfferStatistics(token, payload)
    
    // Set statistics values in cells
    sheet_statistics.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(statistics.metric)
        
    sheet_statistics.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(statistics.value)
```

Comment: data_statistics is a 2d array so you need 2 indices to specify a single cell

Comment: You can use getFormulas() to get an array of formulas. And if a given cell in that array is not null then that cell is a formula so you can use the formula for that cell and when use setValues() the formula will be inserted in the specified range

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for answering so promptly. I actually do not want to insert the formula into cells, i use the formula to fill the fields before executing the script - however since the length of data (amount of rows needed) varries, i basically need the script to break not only on empty fields (undefined) but also on fields with just a formula ?  - I edited the question as it wasnt clear :D

Comment: The use getFormulas() to determine which cells have formulas

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas), which returns

  - empty strings for no formulas

```
  const data_statistics_rg = sheet_statistics.getDataRange(),
  data_statistics = data_statistics_rg.getValues(),
  data_statistics_formulas = data_statistics_rg.getFormulas();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data_statistics.length; i++) {
    if (data_statistics[i] === undefined) {
         break;
    }
    else if (!data_statistics_formulas[i][0].includes("")) {
         break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks TheMaster, i will try this, but see an issue already with the data_statistics_rg

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster this code did work after a few tweeks. Great Support!

Comment: @CS05 Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkbox on the left of the answer.